# Add a .CSS style element to a link button in JQuery Mobile

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, button, hyperlink

I want to add a `Style` to a `link button` element in `JQuery`. Following is my code which is not working. How can I achieve this? Any suggestions?

Here is the `HTML`

```
<div data-role="content">
    <a href="#" class="linkBUTTONS" data-role="button" onclick="exitLogin()">EXIT</a>
</div>
```

Here is the `CSS`.

```
.linkBUTTONS{
    color: #1dace3;
}
```

Any help is much appreciated, as I am pretty new to `HTML/CSS` and `JQuery Mobile`.

**UPDATE**

When I put it like this, style as an attribute of the given link, it works.

```
<a href="#" style="color: #1dace3;" data-role="button" onclick="exitLogin()">EXIT</a>
```

But when I put it in a separate `StyleSheet` it doesn't work.

Comment: It does work, please state your problem more clearly. Here is a fiddle of same: http://jsfiddle.net/Lgwvstew/

Comment: I have stated the problem, haven't I? The Exit button is not colored to the given color.

Comment: If you'll check the fiddle, i gave link, the button is actually getting colored, tried with 3 different colors. So, I have to assume, there is some part of question that you forgot to mention. I can provide the complete html code, i'll be able to assist in a better way...

Comment: Yeah, I took a look at the fiddle, thanks. I've updated the problem.

Comment: When u r putting in separate stylesheet, u r including the same into ur code, right?? Also, if can u provide the code for same, it'll be great...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for the precedence. There maybe other rules that override your style. You can check all this in developers mode. Also you can try writing rules with !important. Did you try changing class name to link-buttons or something other? Example

```
.link-buttons {
     color: red!important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks DasBoot. It worked for me. It's JQuery Mobile and the button is inside <div data-role="content">.